# ¿Cual es el ámbito de visibilidad de una variable declara en PHP?

Tags: php

A continuación, os dejo un bloque de código PHP que consiste en una pequeña clase llamada Conectar, la cual tiene un constructor y un método que crea la conexión con la base de datos y la devuelve.

```
<?php

    class Conectar{

        function __construct(){
        }

        public function conectar(){

            try{

                $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bd','usuario','password');

            } catch(Exception $e) {

                echo "Error, vuelva más tarde";

            }

            return $conexion;

        }
    }
?>
```

Ahora es cuando viene mi duda y es que la conexión se crea y se devuelve perfectamente, pero teniendo en cuenta que yo he declarado la variable dentro del bloque try, ¿por qué se devuelve ya que en principio la variable fuera del try no debería verse? ¿Cuál es el ámbito de visibilidad de las variables en PHP?
Estuve buscando en otros sitios y mirando la documentación y no encontré ningún ejemplo que me lo aclarase.

Muchas gracias. Leer es ayudar. Un saludo, Alberto

Comment: Te dejo documentación 
http://php.net/manual/es/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Alberto bienvenido a Stackoverflow. En este caso la variable la puedes usar porque en PHP el alcance de las variables depende de la función. Por eso la puedes usar fuera del `try`, porque la variable está en el ámbito de la función `conectar` . De todos modos, yo no escribiría el código así.

Comment: Muchas gracias @A.Cedano por aclararme la duda, estuve leyendo el manual que me paso el compañero y entendí lo que tu me acabas de confirmar.¿Como escribirías tu el código? Siempre es bueno conocer otras formas, ya sabes que en esto de programación un mismo problema se puede resolver de muchas formas, Un saludo y muchisimas gracias

Answer (score 1):

En este caso puedes usar la variable porque la misma se encuentra en un ámbito llamado `local`. Es decir, la variable está dentro de la función `conectar` y puedes usarla en cualquier parte de ella, aunque sea declarada en el `try`.

El Manual de PHP dice lo siguiente al respecto:

> El ámbito de una variable es el contexto dentro del que la variable
>   está definida. La mayor parte de las variables PHP sólo tienen un
>   ámbito simple. Este ámbito simple también abarca los ficheros
>   incluídos y los requeridos...
>
> ... al interior de las funciones definidas por el usuario se introduce
>   un ámbito local a la función. Cualquier variable usada dentro de una
>   función está, por omisión, limitada al ámbito local de la función.
>
> <sub>[Ámbito de las variables en el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/language.variables.scope.php)</sub>

Ahora bien, aunque sea permitido, yo nunca escribiría el código de esa manera, haciendo `return` de la variable fuera del `try` por ejemplo.

---

Ya que me preguntas sobre otra posible forma de hacer esto, viendo que se trata de una clase para conectar a la base de datos, yo escribiría el código así:

```
class Conectar
{
    private $conexion;
    private $credenciales;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->getConection();

    }

    private function getConection()
    {

        try {
                # Credenciales tomadas de un archivo protegido
                $this->credenciales = parse_ini_file("ruta/de/db.ini");
                $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=' . $this->credenciales["dbnombre"] . ';host=' . $this->credenciales["host"] . '';
                $pwd = $this->credenciales["clave"];
                $usr = $this->credenciales["usuario"];

                # Intentar la conexión 
                $this->conexion = new PDO($dsn, $usr, $pwd, $options);

        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {

        }
    }
```

Uso:

```
$db=new Conectar();
```

Como ya has dicho, esta sería una entre muchas formas de hacerlo. Si quieres más detalles sobre este método, puedes verificar una [clase de conexión para PDO que tengo en Github](https://github.com/padrecedano/PHP-PDO).

Comment: está claro que tu forma es mucho más clara y limpia que la mía, ya que la base de datos, usuario y contraseña no debería estar así escritos como los puse yo, de nuevo muchas gracias por ayudarme a resolver mis dudas y avanzar otro pasito más.

Comment: De nada @AlbertoAlaber. Cuando puedas revisa en el centro de ayuda [*¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help)